# JavaScript on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am submitting a ColdFusion Form and I want to run some JavaScript to check field validation before I run my ColdFusion code to process the form as needed.

How can I do this? What do I do in JS to call my .cfm file after the form passes validation?

Thanks!

-Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
<form name="myform" action="myserverscript.cfm" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

if you return true the form submits, false it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

i hope you're doing the validation on the server side as well. never rely on just javascript to scrub your data.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery - http://jquery.com/ 
validation addin for jquery  - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

very simple to do tons of example on jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `onclick` event to your input button, for example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validate()">
```

Then the validate method will be responsible for checking form values. The validate method should return `true` if the form is valid, thus `committing` the form submit. If it returns `false` the form is not submitted. This is how it works for HTML, JavaScript and forms.

In addition, the docs linked by *mark* should help you further.